# Thinking maybe I should migrate a question

Tags: support, questions, migration

I asked this:

[Auto-forwarding messages on a Facebook group to a mailing list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59689/auto-forwarding-messages-on-a-facebook-group-to-a-mailing-list)

on WebApps.SX ; on second though, I think maybe it's a better fit on this site (e.g. because it doesn't actually have to do anything with a mailing list and is just as relevant for individual use), but I've never migrated (or cross-posted) anything myself, and I don't want to get shouted at for doing something I'm not supposed to. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your question to be moved to another site, flag it on the site it's currently on and tell the moderators that you would like to have it moved to another site. Never cross-post!

That being said, the question you mentioned is a tricky one. Because it's about Facebook specifically, it might not be well received on Super User, as questions like that are usually better suited for WebApps.

So, it's possible that the WebApps mods would migrate your question, only for it to be closed here for being off-topic.